# Famo.us scrollview not scrolling

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to make a Scrollview out of views that would contain several surfaces (or even views inside), but it then does not scroll. It just populates the content till fold and doesn't scroll any further down (doesn't respond to mouse wheel or touch gestures).

A function in the view class that creates the Scrollview :

```
function _createScrollView () {

    this.scrollView = new Scrollview();
    var surfaces = [];

    this.scrollView.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

    for (var i = 0, temp; i < 40; i++) {

        temp = new ContentRow({ orderNumber : i });

        temp.pipe(this.scrollView);
        surfaces.push(temp);
    }

    this.scrollViewMod = new StateModifier({
        transform : Transform.translate(0, 80, 0)
    });

    this.add(this.scrollViewMod).add(this.scrollView);
}
```

And this is the full ContentRow class that I was expecting to develop further in detail and be a part of bigger scrollview sequence:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
var View          = require('famous/core/View');
var Surface       = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Transform     = require('famous/core/Transform');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

function ContentRow() {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    this.add(new Surface({
             content: "Surface: " + (this.options.orderNumber + 1),
             size: [undefined, 200],
             properties: {
                 backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (this.options.orderNumber * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                 lineHeight: "200px",
                 textAlign: "center"
             }
        }))
}

ContentRow.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
ContentRow.prototype.constructor = ContentRow;

ContentRow.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    orderNumber : 0        
};

module.exports = ContentRow; 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pipe the surface within ContentRow to ContentRows _eventOutput..

ContentRow should look as follows..

Hope this helps!

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {

  var View          = require('famous/core/View');
  var Surface       = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var Transform     = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

  function ContentRow() {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    var surface = new Surface({
         content: "Surface: " + (this.options.orderNumber + 1),
         size: [undefined, 200],
         properties: {
             backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (this.options.orderNumber * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
             lineHeight: "200px",
             textAlign: "center"
         }
    });

    surface.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    this.add(surface);
  }

  ContentRow.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
  ContentRow.prototype.constructor = ContentRow;

  ContentRow.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    orderNumber : 0        
  };

  module.exports = ContentRow; 
});
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer... bump @Harris-deksnis, John needs the points!!  :P